# How to make an IAM Role for a Django Application?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to make an `IAM Role` for my Django app. How can I do this both from **AWS side** and **Django side**? Also, I have heard that this is **best practice**, but don't really understand **why it is important**. Could someone explain? Thanks!

Update for Marcin:

```
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=my_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=my_secret
)
s3 = session.resource('s3')
```

Update 2 for Marcin:

```
client = boto3.client(
        'ses',
        region_name='us-west-2',
        aws_access_key_id=my_key,
        aws_secret_access_key=my_secret
client.send_raw_email(RawMessage=raw_message)
```

Comment: Hi. Depends on what AWS services your app will need to access.

Comment: @Marcin Hey! I need to access **S3** (read and write in a few buckets), **SES** (sending emails), and **SNS** (sending SMS). Thanks!!

Comment: The role is for an instance?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, the role is for an Elastic Beanstalk instance running a Django app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default instance role that EB is using is [aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-instanceprofile.html#iam-instanceprofile-verify). One way to customize it by adding [inline policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#inline-policies) to it in IAM console.

Since you require S3, SES and SNS you can add permissions to them in the inline policy. Its not clear which actions do you require (read only for S3, publish message for SNS only?), or if you have specific resources in mind (e.g. only one given bucket or single sns topic),  you can start by adding full access to the services. But please note that giving full access is a **bad practice** and does not follow [grant least privilege](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege) rule.

Nevertheless, en example of an inline policy with full access to S3, SES and SNS is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sns:*",
                "ses:*",
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The following should be enough:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
```

Comment: I see, this makes sense!! Btw, does the `Version` value matter?

Comment: @NGI Yes, it must be `2012-10-17`. You can't change it.

Comment: Got it, makes sense. Also, how do I connect to this on the Django side (in Python?) Do I just connect to the client with the credentials for it? Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: What do you mean? Once the role is attached to the instance nothing else should be required. All applications which run on the instance and which use AWS SDK should be able to use the role seamlessly.

Comment: I think I might be confused. I updated my question to include how I currently connect to s3 in my Django app without an IAM role. How would I do it with an IAM role attached to the instance? Let me know if I am making no sense ;). Thanks again Marcin!!

Comment: Just `s3 = boto3.resource('s3')` should be enough. Boto3 will use your instance role to get the credentials automatically.

Comment: Locally, on your local workstation? I think best way would be to setup [aws cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) credential files. Boto3 will look for them, when instance role is not found. And as a last resource the hard coding of the keys can be considered, but again this is very bad practice and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge here, but just to confirm, for the **use case**, should I select **EC2** ("Allows EC2 instances to call AWS services on your behalf.") or **Elastic Beanstalk** ("Allows Elastic Beanstalk to create and manage AWS resources on your behalf.")?

Comment: @NGI First check what is the instance profile/role used by your EB. Go to EC2 console, and locate your EB instance. It should be provided in instance details. Then you can modify that role.

Comment: Got it: it says `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role`. When I select that role in IAM, it asks me for a use case though. Let me know if you need any more info!!

Comment: @NGI You go to the role in iam console, on there should be option to add `inline policy` to it.

Comment: Ohhhhhh got it! Thank you SO much!! I'll let you know if I run into anything else

Comment: This worked for the s3 sessions!! However, I can't get it to work for ses. See my updated question for how I am currently sending emails with ses without the iam role. Thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: Yes, the code I put in the question is running on the EB instance.

Comment: @NGI Then can you remove the `aws_access_key_id=my_key` and `     aws_secret_access_key=my_secret` from it. This way instance role will be used with SES permissions.

Comment: It worked!! That should solve it. I did some searching, but can't really seem to understand. What is the difference between `boto3.session` and `boto3.client`? Thanks!!

Comment: I see. Is one more recommended to use?

Comment: @NGI Glad it worked :-) I made mistake in explanation. Here it is again. `boto3.session` represents our "session" of working with the AWS. Most notably it will dictate which credentials and profile to use. While  `client` will actually perform actions on the AWS for the given session. When you use `boto3.client`, you will use "default" session.

Comment: I see, so do you think there is one I should use more here? It sounds like maybe using client would be best? I might be misinterpreting though.

Comment: @NGI On instance, `boto3.client` would be used mostly. On your local workstation, you can have different credential profiles, so you can use different sessions for each.